# Haproxy serving SSL behind CloudFlare

Tags: https, haproxy, cloudflare

we are a small company and we have a Haproxy at front and a few servers behind.

Our SSL certs are served at haproxy directly, "bind *:443 ssl crt /something".

And we signed for the $20 cloudflare plan, for testing and tuning.

And our https connections are insta killed at cloudflare, at firefox we have this error msg: "SSL_ERROR_CYPHER_OVERLAP".

No logs are generated at haproxy.log to help with this problem.

If we take cloudflare , everything works fine.

Is there any special configurations for that scnario:

clients <-cloudflare -> haproxy_https <-> backends.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would be inclined to think that this represents a misconfiguration in your Cloudflare setup, and not related to HAProxy at all... possibly an incorrect assumption on your part, based on your comment, *"Our SSL certs are served at haproxy directly."* That's not exactly how it works.  You can't pass the cert on your HAProxy back "through" Cloudflare... HTTP proxying doesn't work that way.  CloudFlare needs to have a cert for your site, too.  The cert on the proxy only secures the second leg of the connection, between Cloudflare and you.  A different cert handles the browser side.

Answer (score 0):

Try, turning on "Require Modern TLS" in cloudflare:
https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/206029258-How-to-use-Cloudflare-s-Require-Modern-TLS-Feature

I'm also seeing instances of people reporting SSL cert issued by cloudflare can be corrupt so if there is a way to reissue the cert through the CF interface, try that as well.

Lastly, I understand you said there is nothing logging in haproxy so I assume that to mean that you are not seeing any connectivity even from CF as a proxy.  However, just to be sure, something to can test is the SSL cert and cipher that you are using with haproxy (turn off cloudflare):
https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/